# Generate random password for Oracle user using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell

I am trying to write a shell script which randomly creates password and those password should be set to oracle users. I need a Linux command to generate the password which follows the constraints such as :

1.Each time the generated random password should be of length dynamically ranging from 6 to 12 characters.
2.It should follow password standards as proposed by Oracle. It is better if we have only the special characters mentioned by us will be used to generate the password randomly.

I used this cmd:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 12 | head -n 1
```

This is good but 2 changes I need . The generated password length should be dynamically ranging from 6 to 12 characters . and I should mention some special characters to be used to generate random password

Comment: `man pwgen`, if you don't have it, install it.

Comment: What have you tried ? Is shell based solution required - or can you install password generation tool, as suggested

Comment: _It should follow password standards as proposed by Oracle. It is better if we have only the special characters mentioned by us will be used to generate the password randomly._ This sounds more like a requirement for a work order than request for help in your coding problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the passwords be more secure if they were always generated with the maximum length?

Comment: Maximum length is fine but I think all the passwords should not be of same length @IanAbbott

Comment: @JamesBrown If my request sounds like that am sorry . English is not my native language.

Comment: Replace the `head -n 1` with `head -c $((6+$RANDOM%7))`. And lose the `fold`, too. Maybe `;echo` in the end.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that for example password should not start with digit. Theoretically Oracle supports it, if such a password is double quoted, but for even internal Oracle's tools have problem with it. Also password can contain '@' special character but it is a chalenge to use it in sqlplus.

Comment: "... but I think all the passwords should not be of same length".  No, a cryptographic process to crack a password is not going to be confused by the fact that some other password is a different length. Cryptographically, the longer the password the stronger the password. Period. Full stop. Also, in selecting what special characters to introduce, '@', '$', and '!' have all shown to create problems in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My text in the comments was so confusing that I'll write this out. I'll leave it there for laughs:

```
$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c $((6+$RANDOM%7)) ; echo
```

The `echo` appends a newline in the end.

Comment: Great its working and Just one more thing to add . Special characters like `#_$` should be included as a part of the randomly generated password

Comment: Just add the special characters to the `tr`, like `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9#_$'`.